# IndexError: list index out of range(it must be dictionary, not list)

Tags: python

```
EX_GRAPH1 = {0:[1,4,5],
         1:[2,6],
         2:[3],
         3:[0],
         4:[1],
         5:[2],
         6:[]
         }
```

This function Takes a directed graph digraph 
(represented as a dictionary) and computes
the in-degrees for the nodes in the graph.

```
def compute_in_degrees(digraph):
in_degrees = {}
i = 0
j = 0
matches = []
while i < len(digraph):
    m = 0
    while j < len(digraph):
        if digraph[i][j] == i: <--- HERE IndexError: list index out of range
            j += 1
            m += 1
            matches.append(m)
        else:
            j += 1
    in_degrees[i] = matches
    i += 1
return in_degrees
print compute_in_degrees(EX_GRAPH1)
```

help please

Comment: That should be `while j < len(digraph[i]):` (the dictionary is longer than its values are!) or just use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
while j < len(digraph[i]):
```

Currently, you are just repeating the loop for `i`, so you may overrun. Or, as @jonrsharpe said in the comments, use a for loop:

```
def compute_in_degrees(digraph):
    in_degrees = {}
    i = 0
    j = 0
    matches = []
    for i, sublist in enumerate(digraph):
        m = 0
        for j in sublist:
            if j == i:
                m += 1
                matches.append(m)
        in_degrees[i] = matches
    return in_degrees
print compute_in_degrees(EX_GRAPH1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over `i` x `j` entries but `digraph` (`EX_GRAPH1` is passed in) is not a 2D array, it's a sparse array.

Some entries are 0, 1, 2, 3 entries long.

Don't use a `dict`.  Consider `numpy` and/or `networkx`.